# Android Studio 0.4.2 gradle build error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting an error today when I try to build in Android Studio:

```
11:32:11 AM Gradle '...' project refresh failed:
        Cause: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;
        Gradle settings
```

When I try ./gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace, I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '...'.
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project '...'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;
    at com.android.builder.DefaultSdkParser.initParser(DefaultSdkParser.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.SdkParser$initParser.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.Sdk.loadParser(Sdk.groovy:126)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.Sdk$loadParser.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLoadedSdkParser(BasePlugin.groovy:309)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getRuntimeJarList(BasePlugin.groovy:354)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createProguardTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:1521)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.addPackageTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:1212)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.createApplicationVariant(AppPlugin.groovy:607)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.this$3$createApplicationVariant(AppPlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.createTasksForDefaultBuild(AppPlugin.groovy:351)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.doCreateAndroidTasks(AppPlugin.groovy:202)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:280)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:223)
    ... 36 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.585 secs
```

This error was occurring on 0.4.0, and updating to 0.4.2 didn't fix it. Here's part of my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.9'
}
```

I was able to build yesterday, and the code hasn't changed since then - someone I work with is able to build on his machine using the same code. Any ideas?

Comment: What has changed about your personal environment since the last successful build? Judging by your last sentence, it's something wrong with your local configuration.

Comment: please check if proper sdk path is given at `File > Peoject Structure >Android SDK` .

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I can't think of anything that has changed. Two of my other coworkers are getting the error as well (all except one) so I doubt it's some local change that I made since yesterday.

Comment: There's bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64864 to track this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using gradle or the gradle wrapper, however you have your project setup, refresh dependencies seems to have solved this problem for me.

[gradle|./gradlew] --refresh-dependencies && [gradle|./gradlew] assemble[Debug|Release]